# Finding max and min values in a series of numbers In C prgram (error in my code)

Tags: c, for-loop, max, min

This may prove to be a really easy task but I can't seem to grasp what I've done wrong. I've looked for the answer that specifies exactly this execution but can't get it right. My program is supposed to only run 10 times only but it keeps looping until i close the application window. I am new to this so...

```
#include < stdio.h >

int main()

{


    int n, sum = 0, c, value;
    n = 10;
    int max = 0;
    int min = 0;



    printf("Write 10 numbers\n");

    for (c = 1; c <= n; c++)
    {
        scanf_s("%d", &value);


        if (c = 1)
        {
            max = value;
            min = value;


        }
        else if (value < max, c <= n)
        {
            max = value;
        }

        else if (value < min, c <= n)
        {
            min = value;
        }
    }

    printf("Biggest number is : %d\n", max);
    printf("Smallest number is : %d\n", min);



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your [compiler](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c722de5f3a2d6be) should be able to help.

Comment: You have a very weird conditional expressions in your if's

Comment: That's why it's considered a good practice to put the constants first on comparisons

Comment: @Leeor, Personally, I find it rather pointless. It sacrifices the natural flow of the condition to stop an error that the compiler will catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are using assignment operator `=` instead of comnparison operator `==`

```
if (c = 1)
```

The loop for finding minimum and maximum can be written simpler

```
for ( c = 1; c <= n; c++ )
{
    scanf_s( "%d", &value );

    if ( c == 1 )
    {
        max = value;
        min = value;
    }
    else if ( max < value )
    {
        max = value;
    }
    else if ( value < min )
    {
        min = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: There seem to be no point comparing c against 1 in each iteration, so max=-INT_MAX; min=INT_MAX outside the loop is preferable. INT_MAX and others are defined in limits.h

Comment: @user1666959 If you use one loop for finding maximim or minimum you have to use always the condition c == 1.

Comment: Are you claiming that one can not find the min and the max in one loop without the c == 1 bit???

Comment: @user1666959  Yes i wanted to say this.

Comment: @user1666959  I understood that you will start now to speak about INT_MAX and INT_MIN but ut is a bad approach.

Comment: I guess the loop wont sep a value for max or min if you wont set it in the first loop execution. But there could be other ways of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a version without the c == 1 comparison, seems to do it for me. Test cases included below. Please show a counter example, if you think it fails on reasonable input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int value;
int min=INT_MAX, max=-INT_MAX, n=5;
for (int c = 1; c <= n; c++ )
  {
    scanf( "%d", &value );

    if ( max < value )
    {
      max = value;
    }
    if ( value < min )
    {
      min = value;
    }
  }
printf("min = %d\nmax = %d\n", min, max);
return 0;
}

stackoverflow$ ./minmax
2
-10
99
3
3
min = -10
max = 99
stackoverflow$ ./minmax
1
1 
1
1
1
min = 1
max = 1
```

Comment: Thanks anyway but I was not supposed to use anything other than <stdio.h>